# Using MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function like an ape

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with the function called `GROUP_CONCAT`.

My table:

```
"CUSTOMS 
(
    SHIPMENTS VARCHAR(255), 
    X INTEGER,
    Y INTEGER, 
    Z INTEGER,
    T INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (X,Y,Z)"
```

Now this is the query I try to run in general I know there will be a lot of syntax problems. I would be more then happy if you correct me and tell me what I do wrong

The query using the function

```
"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SHIPMENTS) AS CUSTOMSREQUEST 
 FROM CUSTOMS 
 WHERE (X,Y,Z) BETWEEN (?,?,?) AND (?,?,?) AND SHIPMENTS != (?)" {
```

I want to explain what I tried to do: basically I try to select a `group_concat` I use distinct method so the same shipments won't appear afterwards it I use AS CUSTOMREQUEST (dummy to return the string later.), after wards it FROM CUSTOMS < the table WHERE trying to get radius of X,Y,Z and at the end i try to filter specific string from the output...

This is the error I get:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

It should return a single column as well...

What did I do wrong here? (I'm a newbie so please be bad ass with me thanks!)

Comment: I've moved the comment to an answer. You should be able to accept that now.

Answer (score 0):

The [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator only takes one value on each side, and is checking the 2 values against 1 value/column. You should rewrite the query to something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SHIPMENTS) AS CUSTOMSREQUEST 
FROM CUSTOMS 
WHERE x between ? and ? and y between ? and ? and z between ? and ? AND SHIPMENTS != (?)
```